# About the formation of the word "euthanasia"

Tags: etymology, greek, derivation

The etymology of **euthanasia** is pretty straightforward, as [this site](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/euthanasia) shows:

> Early 17th century (in the sense ‘easy death’): from Greek, from *eu*
>   ‘well’ + *thanatos* ‘death’.

What is less straightforward, though, is how come **-thanasia** was formed off the Greek noun **thanatos**.

In my opinion, **-thanasia** should have been the end result if the Greek word for "death" would have been `*thanasos: < *thanas- + -ia`.

Hence, based on the same model, **euthanasia** should really have been `*euthanatia: *thanatos: < *thanat- + -ia`.

Comment: *-tia* tended to be changed to *-cy* in English: compare *necromancy*, *clemency*. In recent borrowings the spelling remains but the pronunciation shifts, as in *dementia*. *-ti-* was generally not a stable sound.

Answer (score 3):

One thing that the Oxford Dictionaries entry may not make entirely clear is that the Greek word εὐθανασία was derived much earlier than the 17th century. It is listed in the [LSJ](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=substring&lookup=qanas&lang=greek), along with seven other words containing the sequence "θανασι". A sound change that applied in a certain stage of Greek changed -ti- to -si- ([mentioned in this Linguistics SE answer by TKR](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/13119/5581)). I don't know the details of how these words were derived, but I would guess that this sound change is responsible for the **s** in *euthanasia.*